# Evaluate the integral: $\int\frac{dp_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\sigma_j}{1-p_j} }$

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate the following indefinite integral. Fix some $i\in{1,..,n}$

$$\int\frac{dp_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\sigma_j}{1-p_j} }$$

Here $\sigma_j$s are positive constants adding up to 1, whereas $p_j\in(0,1)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of $p_i$, the denominator is $A_i + \frac{\sigma_i}{1-p_i}$
where $A_i = \sum_{j \ne i} \frac{\sigma_j}{1- p_j}$ does not depend on $p_i$.
Thus your integral is
$$ \int \dfrac{dp_i}{A_i + \sigma_i/(1-p_i)} = \frac{p_i}{A_i} + \frac{\sigma_i}{A_i^2} \ln(A_i (1-p_i) + \sigma_i) + C$$